# drawing circle by clicking using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas

I am trying to **plot a circle** in a plot based on the **mouse click**. I have written a code but its not drawing a circle on click.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([-40, 40])
ax.set_ylim([-40, 40])
ax.set_aspect('equal')

def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick:
        circle=plt.Circle((event.xdata,event.ydata),2.5,color='black')
        ax.add_patch(circle)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        circle = plt.Circle((event.xdata,event.ydata),2.5,color='black')
        ax.set_xlim([-40, 40])
        ax.set_ylim([-40, 40])
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.add_artist(circle)
        plt.show()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alternatively adding this as last line in the function has also solved the issue. fig.canvas.draw()

Comment: No problem, and yes, `fig.canvas.draw()` or `plt.show()` would both have worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([-40, 40])
ax.set_ylim([-40, 40])
ax.set_aspect('equal')

def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick:
        circle=plt.Circle((event.xdata,event.ydata),2.5,color='black')
        ax.add_patch(circle)
        fig.canvas.draw() #this line was missing earlier
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
```